# Is there official Xamarin github repo for cross-platform framework project?

Tags: github, xamarin

If I search for "Xamarin github repo", I get directed to https://github.com/xamarin where there are 178 repos. When I search for "React Native github repo", for example, then I get directed to the actual repo https://github.com/facebook/react-native. How can I find the official github repo of xamarin cross-platform framework?

P.S I am not interested in project samples. I am specifically looking for the project repo itself.

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms for the project repo itself.

Comment: What are you looking for? The runtime? Xamarin.Forms, something else?

Comment: FYI: One reason for multiple repos is "Xamarin Native" vs "Xamarin Forms". There are two ways to use Xamarin: "Xamarin Native" means developing a single-platform project (e.g. ios or Android), using that platform OS's APIs, but in c# instead of the platform's native language. Thus, "Xamarin.iOS" and "Xamarin.Android" are useful on their own, though not cross-platform. E.g. on iOS, the UI is classes such as "UIViewController", controlled via a Storyboard. "Xamarin.Forms" builds on these, to provide a cross-platform UI. (Maui equivalents are ".Net 6+ for iOS/Android", on which Maui UI is built.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you for your comment! You made everything clear. If you post it as your answer, I will accept it :).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thanks for the link! With comment from ToolmakerSteve I can also understand why exactly I should refer to Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason for multiple repos is "Xamarin Native" vs "Xamarin Forms".

There are two ways to use Xamarin:

- "Xamarin Native" means developing a single-platform project (e.g. iOS or Android), using that platform OS's APIs, but in c# instead of the platform's native language. Thus, "Xamarin.iOS" and "Xamarin.Android" are useful on their own, though not cross-platform. E.g. on iOS, the UI is classes such as "UIViewController", controlled via a Storyboard. (Maui equivalents are ".Net 6+ for iOS/Android".)
- "Xamarin.Forms" builds on these, to provide a cross-platform UI. (Maui is the updated UI API, when targetting .Net 6+.)